# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 499

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to make an AutoEncoder and am stuck at the above error. Looking at other posts with this on Stack Exchange didn't help.

Here is the error in full:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 499
 [[{{node metrics_12/acc/Squeeze}}]]
 [[{{node ConstantFoldingCtrl/loss_12/time_distributed_6_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Switch_0}}]]
```

I can compile my model. Here it is:

> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= lambda_7 (Lambda)            (None, 499, 22)           0
>   _________________________________________________________________ cu_dnnlstm_14 (CuDNNLSTM)    (None, 300)               388800
>   _________________________________________________________________ repeat_vector_12 (RepeatVect (None, 499, 300)          0
>   _________________________________________________________________ cu_dnnlstm_15 (CuDNNLSTM)    (None, 499, 50)           70400
>   _________________________________________________________________ time_distributed_6 (TimeDist (None, 499, 22)           1122
>   ================================================================= Total params: 460,322 Trainable params: 460,322 Non-trainable params:
>   0

The lambda layer takes a padded sequence of shape (1,499) and converts it to a onehot with 22 possible values. I then pass this through an encoding CuDNNLSTM, a repeat vector, another CuDNNLSTM and then a time distributed dense layer with a softmax activation.

I use:

```
model.compile('rmsprop', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

And:

```
model.fit(s_min_one, s_min_one,
   batch_size=batchS,
   epochs=epochS,
   verbose = 1,  
   shuffle=True)
```

Which gives me my error.

I use the sparse categorical so that my data can be in integer format taking on values between 0 and 21 (for the 22 features). And I don't understand why the error expects a dimension of 1 for anything. It is almost as if it wants me to flip my columns and rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is related to the shape of the output. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects integer targets (see [the documentation](https://keras.io/losses/): "When using the sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets should be *integer* targets.")

You are passing data which is of shape `(batch_size, 1, 499)` both as the input as well as the labels:

```
model.fit(s_min_one, s_min_one, ...)
```

That's not going to work, the labels need to be of shape `(batch_size, 1)` or simply `(batch_size,)`.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you need to adapt the loss function accordingly.