# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for 'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,4]

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow - 2.1.0

Python - 3.6

I have searched this issue on stackoverflow but could not find solution.

I am trying to create a chatbot using tensorflow. This is error:

> Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for
>   'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,4].

This is code:

```
words = []
    classes = []
    documents = []
    ignore_words = ['?', '!']
    data_file = open('fil.json').read()
    intents = json.loads(data_file)
    for intent in intents['intents']:
        for pattern in intent['question']:
            w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(w)
            documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
            if intent['tag'] not in classes:
                classes.append(intent['tag'])
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))
    pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
    pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))
    training = []
    output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
    for doc in documents:
        bag = []
        pattern_words = doc[0]
        pattern_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
        for w in words:
            bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)
        output_row = list(output_empty)
        output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1

        training.append([bag, output_row])
    random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training)
    train_x = list(training[:, 0])
    train_y = list(training[:, 1])
    print("Training data created")
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5)
    model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)

    print("model created")
```

Comment: Why doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634133/can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-2?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843073/can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-5?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203072/can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-499?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I have seen solutions. I tried changing loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy" to loss="categorical_crossentropy" because I have categorical output. But this is giving error "AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value' "  and I don't know where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, since your model is using softmax dense layer as output, you should set its loss to `categorical_crossentropy`. The error you get after that is a [known issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13353). There's a few options that could help you to fix it:

- Check your Python environment. Ensure that you don't have Keras installed along with TensorFlow and that your `Keras-Applications` and `Keras-Preprocessing` packages are up to date.
- In `model.fit()` call set `workers=0`.
- Try to downgrade your TensorFlow package to 2.0.1.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. In the end, I was saving the model using save(). Problem was I was using keras to load the model (load_model()). I replaced that with tf.keras.models.load_model() (imported tensorflow as tf). It worked without uninstalling Keras(Although I am going to uninstall) or downgrading Tensorflow. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please check it should be "categorical_crossentropy" not "sparse_categorical_crossentropy".